# Magento Store - Get Base URL in Static Block

Tags: magento

I have a static block in Magento with this content:

```
<li><a href="#/contacts">Contact Us</a></li>
```

I would like to replace the # with the site's base url.  I want it to retrieve this dynamically.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Try adding this to your static block:

```
<a href="{{store url=""}}">Link to Base URL</a>
```

That should create a link to your store's base URL.

Comment: within PHP: $baseurl = Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseUrl();

Answer (score 19):

you can use this `{{store direct_url="contacts"}}`

For example:

```
<a href="{{store direct_url="contacts"}}">contact us</a>
```

Answer (score 9):

For those that are still looking for a solution, the following should do the trick for you...

For the unsecured base URL:

```
{{config path='web/unsecure/base_url'}}
```

Or for the secured base URL:

```
{{config path='web/secure/base_url'}}
```

Comment: this doesn't include store code (if in url) and `{{store url=""}}` uses safe or unsafe url automagically

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<a href="{{store url="contacts"}}">Contact Us</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add store URL in static block:

```
<a href="{{store direct_url='identifier'}}">Your link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

**A bit more clear and practical scenario (for all level of users) would be:**
Suppose, we have added a static-block in footer-area/elsewhere. In that static-block we have words like this: *Contact Us*
And we want to add a cms-page link of that words(Contact Us).

Nice and simple way with elaborated steps:

**Step-1:** Create a page through CMS>Pages. In 'Page Information' Tab section we set URL Key* `page-contact-us`
Necessary Text can be written through the content tab area.

**Step-2:** After opening up our Static-block through CMS>Static Blocks, we have to write the code like this way:

`<a href="{{store url="page-contact-us"}}">Contact Us</a>`

That's all, the Base URL of that Static-block is now activated and can be retrieved dynamically.